# Intuition for Impact Crater Diameter Relationship with Impactor Mass

Tags: mass, collision

Recent experiments that I have been carrying out dropping balls into sand suggest a relationship between impact crater diameter and impactor mass of: D = kM^0.31 where M is mass, k constant, and D is diameter of crater. I have done extensive research online but I can’t find a comprehensible intuition nor derivation for why diameter might be proportional to the cube root of mass, especially given that I want such an explanation to be generalisable to simple collisions between balls and sand. Any knowledge or insight at all to share or references to useful material on crater formation would be appreciated.

Comment: @POW8J6 I was once told that the it was simply the energy required to excavate the material originally inside the crater, but I think that would go as the 4th power of the crater radius (i.e. volume x depth) - which would lead to M^0.25. So I too am curious to hear a good answer.

Comment: This  https://nuclearweaponsedproj.mit.edu/Node/22  says nuclear weapon crater width is roughly proportional to $W^{1/3}$, or roughly the power of 0.333. You got 0.31.

Comment: @POW8J6 I did a bit of digging but couldn't find a good answer either. There seem to be two regimes:. First when most of the energy goes to deforming or destroying or otherwise removing the volume of material in the crater - in which case the diameter goes as energy^(1/3). Second when most of the work is done lifting the material out of the crater against gravity - in which case the diameter goes as energy^(1/4).  For large planetary craters, the latter should dominate.